# Does every co-bounded set contain a club?

Tags: set-theory

**Definition.** A subset of a cardinal is a *club* if it is closed in the order topology and unbounded.

Let $\kappa$ be an infinite cardinal such that the intersection of two clubs is always a club. Is that true that every co-bounded set of $\kappa$ contains a club?

If $X$ is co-bounded (that is $\kappa\setminus X$ is bounded), it is clear that $X$ is unbounded but I don't know how to show it contains a close set (itself unbounded).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to a comment by Mark Kamsma, I figured out that the answer is indeed positive. One has simply to consider the following set

$\{\alpha\in X:\alpha>\sup(\kappa\setminus X)\}$.

And we don't actually need the hypothesis about intersection.